# SSRS ReportViewer fails when using parameters

Tags: reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I'm using the ReportViewer control in VS2010.

In my local and development environments when I use:

```
    ReportParameter[] toReportParameterList = new ReportParameter[1];
    toReportParameterList[0] = new ReportParameter("intApplicationID", Session["APPLICATION_ID"]);
    rvFinancialSummaryReport.ServerReport.SetParameters(toReportParameterList);
```

Everything works properly.

When I try to do the exact same thing in my Staging/Beta environment, I get an HTTP 401 not authorized error.

When I comment out those three lines, the report parameter section loads and I can get the report correctly when I type in the parameter.

Any idea why trying to pass parameters via the server report, I get an HTTP 401?

**EDIT**

I should probably add that I am sending credential information as such:

```
    string tsUserNameDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportUserName"].ToString();
    string tsDomain = tsUserNameDomain.Substring(0, tsUserNameDomain.IndexOf("\\"));
    string tsUsername = tsUserNameDomain.Substring(tsUserNameDomain.IndexOf("\\") + 1);
    string tsPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportPassword"].ToString();
    ReportViewerCredentials toCredentials = new ReportViewerCredentials(tsUsername, tsPassword, tsDomain);
    rvFinancialSummaryReport.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = toCredentials;
```

This works as long as there is no parameters set.

**EDIT**

Just to Reiterate... when I comment this line:

```
rvFinancialSummaryReport.ServerReport.SetParameters(toReportParameterList);
```

It works...

When I uncomment this line:

```
rvFinancialSummaryReport.ServerReport.SetParameters(toReportParameterList);
```

I get an HTTP 401: Unauthorized.

**EDIT**

Another detail... my SSRS server is HTTP, my IIS is HTTPS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the order of operations in this scenario is important.

After some extensive testing on a local server, I realized that after the parameter value was set, when I went to set the credential values the parameter array object on the server report was coming back as null.

I moved the instantiation of the credential object to the top of the page load, and now everything is working properly.